# Windows PowerShell - How to view commands history date/time

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, command

I want to list entered commands in Windows `PowerShell` with their respective timestamps. How can I do it with `Get-History` command?

Also if that isn't doable then please show me a way to check which `urls(network)` at which timestamps have been accessed through the `CMD`.

**Also consider that I've restarted my computer.**

Thanks life savers

Answer (score 3):

Using `format-list` on the result of Get-History will show additional info about past tasks, including execution start and end time.

```
h | format-list
```

Comment: correct but my computer has been restarted, what should I do to view command logs my friend?

Comment: @RaminOmrani it seems to be too late now but if you have control over the restarts you can save your history to reimport it after restart. More info [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156792.aspx).